# Problem calculating f-1 score when when running hyperparameter tuning using Optuna

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost, hyperparameter-tuning

I'm trying to run Stratified CV hyperparameter tuning on an XGBClassifier using Optuna. This is a multiclass problem with 3 classes (labelled 0 through 2 in the "classes" variable). These are the dimensions of the inputs:

- "**x**" is a **(4000, 43)** sparse COO matrix
- "**classes**" is a **(4000,)** dense flat numpy array

I use Hyperband pruning through callbacks and a custom f-1 function (since XGBoost's .cv() method doesn't provide this metric).

The problem is in the function **weighted_f1_score** (which is executed as a callback through the.cv() method), **preds** is a flat array of probabilities, so when I try to use "argmax" to get the predicted class for each sample it returns an error. It would work if only .cv() simply returned class predictions instead of probabilities.

I'm not sure how to solve this and I'm really stumped by this. I hope someone more knowledgeable can help.

Here's the code snippet:

```
import optuna
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from xgboost import cv, DMatrix
import optuna.integration.xgboost as xgb_integration
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score


def objective(trial):

    # Define hyperparameter search space
    params = {

        'objective': 'multi:softmax',
        'n_estimators': trial.suggest_int('n_estimators', 50, 300),
        'learning_rate': trial.suggest_float('learning_rate', 0.001, 1.0, log=True),
        'max_depth': trial.suggest_int('max_depth', 3, 10),
        'min_child_weight': trial.suggest_int('min_child_weight', 1, 10),
        'subsample': trial.suggest_float('subsample', 0.1, 1.0),
        'colsample_bytree': trial.suggest_float('colsample_bytree', 0.1, 1.0),
        'reg_alpha': trial.suggest_float('reg_alpha', 0.01, 10.0, log=True),
        'reg_lambda': trial.suggest_float('reg_lambda', 0.01, 10.0, log=True),
        'gamma': trial.suggest_float('gamma', 0.01, 10.0, log=True)
    }
    
    # Custom weighted F1 score metric for multiclass classification
    def weighted_f1_score(preds, dtrain):
        y_true = dtrain.get_label()
        y_pred = np.argmax(preds, axis=1)
        f1 = f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average='weighted')
        return 'weighted-f1-score', f1
    
    # Stratified Cross-Validation using xgb.cv() with XGBoostPruningCallback
    pruning_callback = xgb_integration.XGBoostPruningCallback(trial, 'test-weighted-f1-score-mean')

    strat_folds = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

    cv_results = cv(params,
                    dtrain = DMatrix(x, label=classes),
                    num_boost_round = 100,
                    folds = strat_folds,
                    early_stopping_rounds = 10,
                    maximize = True,
                    custom_metric = weighted_f1_score,
                    callbacks = [pruning_callback],
                    verbose_eval = False)
    
    # Use the mean value across all folds as the objective:
    return np.mean(cv_results['test-weighted-f1-score-mean'])

# Define Optuna study
study = optuna.create_study(direction = 'maximize', pruner = optuna.pruners.HyperbandPruner())

# Start optimization process:
study.optimize(objective, n_trials = 100,
               n_jobs = os.cpu_count(),
               show_progress_bar=True)

# Get the best parameters
best_params = study.best_params

# Print the best hyperparameters and score
best_trial = study.best_trial
print('Best trial:')
print('Value: {}'.format(best_trial.value))
print('Params: ')
for key, value in best_trial.params.items():
    print('    {}: {}'.format(key, value))


# Retrain XGBClassifier on the whole dataset with the best parameters:
best_xgb = XGBClassifier(**best_params,
                        objective ='multi:softmax',
                        n_jobs = os.cpu_count(),
                        booster='gbtree',
                        tree_method = 'hist',
                        random_state = self.random_state)

# Fit final model:
best_xgb.fit(x, classes)
```

Comment: Can you tell us about what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I actually managed to correct this issue. I needed to use "objective': 'multi:softprob' instead of objective': 'multi:softmax'